# How can I change the state of App.js from a form treatment?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios, react-router-dom

My App.js contains my Router and my routes. I have a route to my Home component and a route to my LoginForm component.

In my LoginForm I use axios (call to an API) for the authentication. I store the user in the localstorage and redirect to my Home component.

In my App.js I have a boolean isLoggedIn in my state. In the `componentDidount` I check if there is something in the localstorage to update my state. I cannot find a way to change the state without refreshing the page.

What should I do to make the update of the state in App.js from my LoginForm component ?

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let state = localStorage["appState"];
        if (state) {
            let AppState = JSON.parse(state);
            this.setState({ isLoggedIn: AppState.isLoggedIn,user: AppState.user });
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className="App">
                    <Route path="/" exact component={BatteryUp} />
                    <Route path="/login" exact component={LoginForm} />
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

LoginForm -> axios then & render

```
.then(response => {
    let appState = { isLoggedIn: true, user: userData };
    localStorage.setItem("appState",JSON.stringify(appState));
    this.setState({ redirect: true });
}

render() {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
        return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
    return (
        <form className="container" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually what redux is used for.  You would update the state in redux, and then the update to the reducer would be propagated to the App.  Another solution would be to have all of this logic contained within the APP component.  Which is not going to make things very modular.